# Emojis length error when Text() - flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I'm trying to show all of the emojis that I have on a JSON file (I stored their Unicode and their description). However, as Flutter cannot check that my keys (the unicode) have a length of 4 it shows an error. What can I do?

```
myEmoji = "\u{$key}";
```

ERROR: Error: An escape sequence starting with '\u' must be followed by 4 hexadecimal digits or from 1 to 6 digits between '{' and '}'.

EDIT: the key stored looks something like this : "1F601"

Comment: `\u` is used for a Unicode *literal*.  It doesn't make sense to use it with variable substitution.  If `key` is already a `String`, it already stores Unicode.  If `key` is an integer, what does it represent?  A codepoint in UTF-32? UTF-16? UTF-8?

Comment: The variable key stores values like "1F601". My bad, I forgot to add it in the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\u` is used for a Unicode *literal*; it is parsed at compile-time.  It cannot be used with a variable.

If you have a `String` with the hexadecimal representation of the Unicode code point, you will need to parse that `String` to an integer value and then use [`String.fromCharCode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCode.html):

```dart
void main() {
  var codePointString = '1F601';
  var codePointValue = int.parse(codePointString, radix: 16);
  var emoji = String.fromCharCode(codePointValue);
  print(emoji); // Prints: 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help. Using the `.runes` method allows you to access the "true" length of a `String` that includes emojis.

```dart
void main() {
  String s = "hey";
  print(s.runes.length); // prints 4
  print(s.length); // prints 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i used s.runes.length but still has wrong length of some emoji, use s.characters.length is more correct, i got this from the LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).